# Django admin select box ordering

Tags: django-admin

How to order foreign key values in Django admin?

ex:

class LeaveBase(models.Model):

```
 User = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name=('User Name'))    
 FinancialYear=models.ForeignKey(FinancialYear,verbose_name=('Financial Year'))
```

In my Django admin when i add a new leavebase the User column shows as select box with the default ordering by id, I would like to order by its name.

Answer (score 1):

this may help: http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/ordering/

Comment: That link is broken, I *think* it means this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering